# Import from csv file to SQL table - Double quotes on the very end

Tags: csv, bulk-insert

I was able to import a .CSV file into my sql table, here is my BULK INSERT script:

BULK INSERT TLS_Sysprocess
FROM 'D:\Dennis\DevAPPServers2.csv'
WITH (
FirstRow=2
,FIELDTERMINATOR = '","'
,ROWTERMINATOR = '"\n"'

)
GO

Notice in the picture, the last column has double quotes:
e.g. MyAppServer2"

Unfortunately, you can only have ONE FIELDTERMINATOR, e.g. FIELDTERMINATOR = '","'

What would be the simplest way of removing this double quote?

I also created this format.fmt to be used for my BULK INSERT, it cannot be read for some reason, here is a snip:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And can you include some sample data as it appears in the file?

Comment: If you're referencing the source file, it would be a list of SQL Server instances.

Comment: Since I'm in a locked environment, the text file would include something like:
servername\instancename,51433

Comment: Since I'm in a locked environment, the text file would include something like:
<servername>\<instancename>,51433
<servername2>\<instancename>,51433  
and so on...the powershell picks this up and generates the .csv file

We actually found a solution, to make a long story short, rather than troubleshooting sql table where the rows exist,I just wipe out the "" in the .csv file before it gets inserted into a table, the command would be:

(Get-Content -Path <path>\file.csv -Raw).replace('"','') | Set-Content -Path <path>\file.csv
Thank you for your reply.